# Android - automating file transfer between phone and desktop app

Tags: android, adb

Does anyone know of a way to transfer files between an app running on a desktop and and app running on an Android device?

Would this have to be some sort of client server arch? Should i use 'adb push / pull' like commands from the desktop app with predifined file paths on the sd card (which the app saves its data too?)

Thanks,

Comment: I suggest you not to use ADB, as you (or specially your customers) will need to enable usb debugging and will probably need a special usb driver. You could try to run an app on the computer that opens a port and receives / sends data to a mobile via http or a custom protocol.

Comment: thanks for the reply - would this be relativly trivial using java (on the desktop)? I guess one would have to configure any firewall running on the comp to allow communication over that port?

Comment: Don't make users forward ports. Use a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use Dropbox, or a similar service. If you want your own solution you can use, for example, sftp. If the phone can be connected to the same wireless net as the desktop computer you don't even have to worry about ports/NAT issues.